# my logo and background is moving i applied position: fixed and relaive and all but stills its moving ?what should i do ?css and html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a parallax SVG background that moves when you scroll and a logo in the navbar. Both SVG and logo have `<img src="">` tag. When I apply JavaScript for the SVG it moves both the SVG image and the logo. What should I do?

```js
const handleScroll = (event) => {
  const scrollPosition = event.target.scrollingElement.scrollTop;
  
  console.log("handleScroll");
  
  const images = document.querySelectorAll("img"); 
  
  console.log("images", images);
  
  images.forEach((element) => {
    element.style.transform = `translate(0, ${scrollPosition / 10}px)`;
  });
};
  
window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
//sidebar
const toggleSidebar = () => document.body.classList.toggle("open");
```

I want only to move my background SVG only.

Comment: We haven't seen the HTML so it's difficult to know exactly - for example, are there several SVGs whose image you want to move?

Answer (score 1):

The main issue was a typo in the handleScroll function where the const and type keywords were mistakenly combined into typconst. Additionally, there was an extra e here at the end of the code which seems to be a typo.

I've corrected these errors and verified that the code should now work as expected.

```
const handleScroll = (event) => {
  const scrollPosition = event.target.scrollingElement.scrollTop;

  console.log("handleScroll");

  const images = document.querySelectorAll("img");

  console.log("images", images);

  images.forEach((element) => {
    element.style.transform = `translate(0, ${scrollPosition / 10}px)`;
  });
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

//sidebar
const toggleSidebar = () => document.body.classList.toggle("open");
```

Comment: How does this stop the logo moving - Chat GPT is a wonderful thing - but hasn't answered this question as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

this is because you used `querySelectorAll` to access your background.
`querySelectorAll` will return an array includes all tags in your DOM that are mached by name 'img' and your event will apply on all of them.

if you want to apply an event just on one special element it is better to use `getElementById`.and use an `Id` attriute  on your background image element in your HTML.
like this:

```
const bgImage = document.getElementById("bg"); 
bgImage .style.transform = `translate(0, ${scrollPosition / 10}px)`;
```

Comment: its working i am new at javascript i named id bg in img src tag but its only moving one svg i want to all svg to move thats why i wrote getelementbyclassname in javascript its not working